# How to Restrict magento admin panel access via particular IP addresses/ranges

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, ce-1.8.1.0

I am newbie in Magento. I want to restrict Magento admin panel access via particular IP addresses/ranges. Please guide me.

Comment: try this module : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-ip-security.html

Answer (score 3):

You can place following in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^196.196.196.196
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

Or you may use following extension: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-ip-security.html